# Swift Blake2B 128 hashing mismatch

Tags: swift, hash, blockchain, substrate

I have this hex string
`0x6469643a737369643a7465737432343700000000000000000000000000000000`
and trying to convert via blake2b 128

**Expected result**: `0x017d8f165615146b5af43b037ee14db4`

Using https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate-js-utilities/

**But in code I'm getting** `6a3f369054a2150757e7a4a8a6f59996`

**Code**

```swift
    let newData = try encodedHexData.blake2b(128)
    let newHex = newData.toHexString()
    print("HEX::: ", newHex)

    func blake2b(_ size: Int) throws -> Data {
        do {
            var hasher = try Blake2(.b2b, size: size / 8)
            hasher.update(self)
            
            return try hasher.finalize()
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    }
```

what should be the correct way?

Ref:

https://github.com/sublabdev/substrate-client-swift

https://github.com/soramitsu/fearless-utils-iOS

Comment: Your website "shawntabrizi" takes a "string" as parameter, not "data", so your website is not giving you the right expectation. Your code is correct.

Comment: @Cœur: But the expectation is the result coming in website, is there any way I can achieve same in local?

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal The hash you get from the web site is the hash you get from pasting the entire string `0x6469...` into the calculator *including the `0x` prefix*. This is surely the wrong result since your encoded HEX data almost certainly doesn't have a `0x` on the front of it.

Comment: I think you guys are right, I tried using bytes array instead of string conversion and got the result as expected. Thanks a lot